# Apply pre_get_posts to specific custom post type in the admin area

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, pre-get-posts

I've created a few CPTs, and wish to have one of the custom post types to query from other post types.

So what I did is I used the codes below to alter the query:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'code_to_alter_query', 10);

function code_to_alter_query($query) {
  // If not backend, bail out
  if( !is_admin() ) return $query;

  $cpts = array('custom_job', 'custom_us_job');
  $query->set( 'post_type', $cpts );

  return $query;
}
```

Now it will show jobs from both `custom_job` and `custom_us_job`. But this will apply to both of the CPTs, what if I want only `custom_job` to have both jobs while `custom_us_job` to have the default query?

I tried using

```
global $pagenow;
```

But this can only get the `edit.php` which will be the same to all the CPTs, how can I determine which (admin) page am I in now?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [`get_current_screen()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen). To check if you are on a specific custom post type page, do as follows:

```
$screen = get_current_screen();
if ( $screen->post_type == 'custom_job' ) {
    // We are on custom_job post type, good to go
}
```

Now, if you visit `edit.php?post_type=custom_job`, this conditional will return true, which you can set your query inside.

There is also another approach for this. By using `is_post_type_archive('custom_job')`, you can target the `edit.php?post_type=custom_job`. Make sure you use this in conjunction with `is_admin()` to make sure you don't target the front-end.

Comment: But when I called get_current_screen(), it gets nothing, it returns an empty value.

Comment: I've updated the answer. @ParkLai